# Select a row in ASP.NET GridView with C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, selectedvalue

I want a row in an ASP.NET `GridView` to be selected with specified value for `SelectedValue`.

The `DataKeyNames` in `GridView` is `SN`, and I have something like this:
    mySN = 5;

I want to find the row in `GridView` its value is equal to `mySN` with `C#` code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"    
 DataKeyNames="id" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

code behind:-

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
int index = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value);

}
```

Comment: With `SelectedIndexChanged` I get the value after index changed. But I want to find a row with a value I already have.